# How to build Eloquent query to retrieve records of the main table, applying where clause on it's related table in Laravel 5 PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-5, many-to-many, polymorphic-relationship

Using the sample many-to-many polymorphic relaltionshiop database structure from Laravel documentation as following:

```
posts
  id - integer
  name - string

videos
  id - integer
  name - string

tags
  id - integer
  name - string

taggables
  tag_id - integer
  taggable_id - integer
  taggable_type - string
```

I would like to retrieve `post` records where `post.name LIKE %laravel%` OR `tags.name LIKE %laravel%`.

How to use Eloquent model to build such query? It is a big challenge to me, since I want to only get posts which their name consists of word `laravel` OR any posts which their related tags have name consisting of the same word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` for this.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas
>   methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods
>   allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint,
>   such as checking the content of a comment

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// Retrieve posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%...
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$input = 'laravel';

Post::whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) use ($input) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $input .'%');
})->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $input . '%')->get();
```

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I am looking for. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$result = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%laravel%')
        ->orWhere('tags.name', 'like', '%laravel%');
})->get();
```

Comment: I have tried this. You get only Post where it's  tags have name consisting of `laravel` but it does not apply the where condition on the post's name itself. The `orWhere(()` function should be called outside the call back of  the `whereHas()` function.